# Split row results into columns

Tags: sql, t-sql

The below query:

```
SELECT  i.Item_ID

  FROM  AGR_Header ah
        LEFT JOIN AGR_Detail ad
               ON ad.AGR_Header_RecID = ah.AGR_Header_RecID
        LEFT JOIN IV_Item i
               ON i.IV_Item_RecID = ad.IV_Item_RecID
```

Shows the following results:

```
a4 black usage page count
a4 colour usage page count
a4 black usage page count
a4 colour usage page count
a4 black usage page count
a4 colour usage page count
a4 black usage page count
a4 colour usage page count
```

Is there a way to create a column for each Item_ID so it displays like:

```
A4 Black                     A4 Colour
a4 black usage page count    a4 colour usage page count
a4 black usage page count    a4 colour usage page count
a4 black usage page count    a4 colour usage page count
a4 black usage page count    a4 colour usage page count
```

I have read about using ROW_NUMBER to assign sequential numbers to each Item_ID or using a PIVOT... unfamiliar with either of these or any other way to accomplish this so any help is appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: What's the relationship between the first black item and the first colour item? How should the query determine which items will be paired together?

Comment: 'a4 black usage page count' == i.Item_ID ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your output is as you mentioned, then you can simply do the following for the desired output:

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(a4b.Item_ID, '') 'A4 Black', 
    ISNULL(a4c.Item_ID, '') 'A4 Color'
FROM
(
  SELECT    i.Item_ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY i.Item_ID ASC) 'RowNum'

  FROM  AGR_Header ah
        LEFT JOIN AGR_Detail ad
               ON ad.AGR_Header_RecID = ah.AGR_Header_RecID
        LEFT JOIN IV_Item i
               ON i.IV_Item_RecID = ad.IV_Item_RecID
  WHERE i.Item_ID LIKE 'a4 black%'
) AS a4b
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
  SELECT    i.Item_ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY i.Item_ID ASC) 'RowNum'

  FROM  AGR_Header ah
        LEFT JOIN AGR_Detail ad
               ON ad.AGR_Header_RecID = ah.AGR_Header_RecID
        LEFT JOIN IV_Item i
               ON i.IV_Item_RecID = ad.IV_Item_RecID
  WHERE i.Item_ID LIKE 'a4 color%'
) AS a4c
ON a4b.RowNum = a4c.RowNum
```

The OUTER JOIN will handle the cases where the number of entries for each of a4 black and a4 color are different.

Comment: If there can be more color or black entries than the other, then you will need an outer join on a4b.RowNum = a4c.RowNum.

Comment: Right @AaronLS, I just wanted to give an idea of how to use ROW_NUMBER and then select the two columns separately and join them. I shall update the answer for it to be complete. Thank you.

Comment: NP, just wanted to make sure they were aware.

Comment: There's no such thing in SQL (particularly in Transact-SQL) as `OUTER JOIN`. Instead, there are `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`, and `FULL OUTER JOIN` (in all cases, `OUTER` is optional). Please specify which of the three you had in mind.

Comment: It was FULL OUTER JOIN, updated the answer. Thanks for pointing out, @AndriyM.

Comment: Thanks Vikdor and everyone else for the updates, that's what I needed!